# Find the number of Characters in a String, recursive Algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, character

If we want to build an algorithm about: "We have an unknown number of characters and "/0" indicates the end of the string. we need to build an algorithm to count the number of characters in the strings. Here is what i did:

Algorithm NumberOfCharacters(A,l,r)

if A[l]=/ and A[l+1]=0
        return l
        else return NumberOfCharacters(A,l+1,r)
I just want to know where is my mistake so that I dont make it again.

Comment: it should be "an unknown number of characters"

Comment: Also what is l, r and m ? You need to define parameters

Comment: "/0" is a character, not 2 characters.

Comment: I am sorry but i used other parameters in my papersheet where i did this work and we use different parameters to describe left and right. l=left, r=right

Comment: they r 2 character not 1

Comment: if r is right index, it means you already know the length ? Otherwise, how do you make the call to this recursive function ?

Comment: but we dont use right index in this algorithm, its just for the purpose of writing

Comment: Remove it. It does nothing and confuse. 
Now, back to question. In C, "/0" is a character. But if your problem definition is different, let assume it is 2 characters.

Comment: Is "/0" considered part of the string or not?

Comment: ok i understand it, but my idea was that we continue repeating the else part until A[l]=/ and A[l+1]=0 and when this is reached we dont have to count but just show the index of last character which should be equal to the number of characters if we start counting from 1.

Comment: @ScottHunter no

Comment: @Albanian i think the pseudo code works now. Do you still get error when run it ? If that the case, may try to check `if A[l]='/0'`

Comment: Remember the single quote, not double quote

Comment: @cuongptnk i havent tested it but my mentor told me it was wrong

Comment: run it. Otherwise, ask your mentor where is the problem. i don't see any problem except the checking of `/0`

Comment: By the way, make sure to call the function with l = 0

Comment: @Albanian start counting from 0, not 1 as you say in above comment.

Comment: @cuongptnk So the idea is right for the algorithm, what about the parameter r which we dont use. Is that a problem?

Comment: It does not cause technical problem. But it does not make sense to include the r parameter.

Comment: I was building it while at class so this can be considered a minor issue @cuongptnk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Algorithm NumberOfCharacters(A,l)

if A[l]=/ and A[l+1]=0
    return l
else 
    return NumberOfCharacters(A,l+1)
```